# Why when I try to install juice shop, I got a lot of mistakes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Then I tried to install juice shop app from [git](https://github.com/juice-shop/juice-shop) after the `npm install` I got a 63 errors

```
[riki@anarchy]: ~/juiceShop/juice-shop>$ npm install
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.10.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

> juice-shop@12.10.0 postinstall
> cd frontend && npm install --legacy-peer-deps && cd .. && npm run build:frontend && (npm run --silent build:server || cd .)

npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.10.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1102.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.1102.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1102.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@11.2.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@11.2.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/cli@11.2.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@ngtools/webpack@11.2.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/angular@11.2.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/update@0.1102.14',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.10.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

> frontend@12.10.0 postinstall
> ngcc --tsconfig "./src/tsconfig.app.json"


up to date, audited 1728 packages in 8s

166 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

27 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 21 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.10.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

> juice-shop@12.10.0 build:frontend
> cd frontend && node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing=none --vendor-chunk=true --source-map=false

Warning: Using differential loading with targets ES5 and ES2016 or higher may
cause problems. Browsers with support for ES2015 will load the ES2016+ scripts
referenced with script[type="module"] but they may not support ES2016+ syntax.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ ES5 bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names                |      Size
vendor-es5.js       | vendor               |   1.59 MB
vendor-es2018.js    | vendor               |   1.44 MB
styles.css          | styles               | 590.10 kB
main-es5.js         | main                 | 402.51 kB
main-es2018.js      | main                 | 379.83 kB
polyfills-es5.js    | polyfills-es5        | 152.48 kB
polyfills-es2018.js | polyfills            |  56.83 kB
runtime-es2018.js   | runtime              |   2.21 kB
runtime-es5.js      | runtime              |   2.21 kB

                    | Initial ES5 Total    |   2.71 MB
                    | Initial ES2018 Total |   2.44 MB

Lazy Chunk Files    | Names                |      Size
tutorial-es5.js     | tutorial             |  30.14 kB
tutorial-es2018.js  | tutorial             |  25.37 kB
8-es5.js            | -                    |  24.84 kB
8-es2018.js         | -                    |  20.08 kB
1-es5.js            | -                    |   7.47 kB
1-es2018.js         | -                    |   7.47 kB
10-es5.js           | -                    |   6.20 kB
10-es2018.js        | -                    |   6.05 kB
9-es5.js            | -                    |   5.28 kB
9-es2018.js         | -                    |   5.17 kB
12-es2018.js        | -                    |   3.28 kB
12-es5.js           | -                    |   3.28 kB
11-es5.js           | -                    |   1.71 kB
11-es2018.js        | -                    |   1.70 kB

Build at: 2021-10-10T13:01:13.085Z - Hash: 4fd8017a8783a22d1bb1 - Time: 70059ms
data/static/codefixes/localXssChallenge_1.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/localXssChallenge_2_correct.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/localXssChallenge_3.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/localXssChallenge_4.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_1.ts:39:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

39   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_1.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_2.ts:37:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_2.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_3.ts:37:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_3.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_4_correct.ts:37:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginAdminChallenge_4_correct.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_1.ts:39:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

39   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_1.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_2_correct.ts:37:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_2_correct.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_3.ts:37:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_3.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_4.ts:36:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

36   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginBenderChallenge_4.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_1_correct.ts:37:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_1_correct.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_2.ts:36:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

36   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_2.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_3.ts:37:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_3.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_4.ts:39:4 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

39   }
      

  data/static/codefixes/loginJimChallenge_4.ts:1:36
    1 module.exports = function login () {
                                         ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_1.ts:37:1 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

37 
   

  data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_1.ts:20:47
    20   for (const { name, exclude } of autoModels) {
                                                     ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_2.ts:24:7 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

24     })
         

  data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_2.ts:19:47
    19   for (const { name, exclude } of autoModels) {
                                                     ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_3_correct.ts:36:6 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

36     }
        

  data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_3_correct.ts:20:47
    20   for (const { name, exclude } of autoModels) {
                                                     ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_4.ts:32:6 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

32     }
        

  data/static/codefixes/registerAdminChallenge_4.ts:20:47
    20   for (const { name, exclude } of autoModels) {
                                                     ~
    The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_1_correct.ts:1:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 ngAfterViewInit () {
                     ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_2.ts:1:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 ngAfterViewInit () {
                     ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_2.ts:57:38 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

57   encodeProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                        ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_2.ts:57:44 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

57   encodeProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                              

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_2.ts:57:47 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

57   encodeProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                                 ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_3.ts:1:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 ngAfterViewInit () {
                     ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_3.ts:43:37 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

43   trustProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                       ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_3.ts:43:43 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

43   trustProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                             

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_3.ts:43:46 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

43   trustProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                                ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_4.ts:1:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 ngAfterViewInit () {
                     ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_4.ts:57:37 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

57   trustProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                       ~

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_4.ts:57:43 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

57   trustProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                             

data/static/codefixes/restfulXssChallenge_4.ts:57:46 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

57   trustProductDescription (tableData: any[]) {
                                                ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:3:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

3     data: { params: (window.location.href).substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#')) },
          ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:3:87 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

3     data: { params: (window.location.href).substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#')) },
                                                                                        ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:5:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

5   },
     ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:8:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8     component: TokenSaleComponent
               ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:9:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

9   },
     ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:12:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

12     component: ErrorPageComponent
                ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:13:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

13   },
      ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:16:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

16     component: SearchResultComponent
                ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_1.ts:18:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

18 ]
   ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:3:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

3     data: { params: (window.location.href).substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#')) },
          ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:3:87 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

3     data: { params: (window.location.href).substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#')) },
                                                                                        ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:5:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

5   },
     ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:8:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8     component: TokenSaleComponent,
               ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:9:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

9     canActivate: [AdminGuard]
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:10:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

10   },
      ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:13:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

13     component: ErrorPageComponent
                ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:14:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

14   },
      ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:17:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

17     component: SearchResultComponent
                ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_2.ts:19:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

19 ]
   ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_3_correct.ts:3:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

3     data: { params: (window.location.href).substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#')) },
          ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_3_correct.ts:3:87 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

3     data: { params: (window.location.href).substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#')) },
                                                                                        ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_3_correct.ts:5:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

5   },
     ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_3_correct.ts:8:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8     component: ErrorPageComponent
               ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_3_correct.ts:9:4 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

9   },
     ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_3_correct.ts:12:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

12     component: SearchResultComponent
                ~

data/static/codefixes/tokenSaleChallenge_3_correct.ts:14:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

14 ]
   ~

data/static/codefixes/xssBonusChallenge_1_correct.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/xssBonusChallenge_2.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/xssBonusChallenge_3.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~

data/static/codefixes/xssBonusChallenge_4.ts:1:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 filterTable () {
                 ~


Found 63 errors.


up to date, audited 2021 packages in 2m

122 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

52 vulnerabilities (13 moderate, 35 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your npm version by running `npm -v`?

My wild guess is you're using npm7, which is not compatible with node v12.

Try downgrade to npm6 instead.

Comment: I had tried to downgrade npm version to 6.11.0 and several others. But non of this don't support me. I'm still have the same 63 errors. I tried to change node.js version too. But it did't work either

Answer (score 0):

The files are all from `data/static/codefixes/` which is [explicitly excluded in the `tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/juice-shop/juice-shop/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L39) by now, so these errors should no longer appear.